# tensorflow_hub not working on google app engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, tensorflow-hub

The following python code is throwing an error on Google App Engine:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Missing implementation that supports: loader(*('/tmp/tfhub_modules/063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003be952409c',), **{})
```

My app.yaml is Standard environment and is using

```
instance_class: F4_1G
```

This works on my local box

Answer (score 0):

Seems like similar issue to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029556/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-missing-implementation-that-supports-loader-when-cal#answer-54074674:%7E:text=I%20walked%20through%20the%20same%20error%20and%20this%20is%20how%20I%20solved%20it%3B). Would you be able to confirm if this mitigation helped in your case?

The error message 'RuntimeError: Missing implementation ...' comes up when using a directory that exists but does not contain a tfhub_module.pb file with a known module format. In particular, you can get this message by trying to load a hub.Module from a directory that contains something else.

Comment: I'm not able to purge /tmp folder as that is created each time the AppEngine starts up. There is no persistance of the /tmp folder either, meaning it gets deleted once the instance is done

Comment: Can you try with 'embed = hub.load(url)'? It seems hub.load is replacing hub.Module in TF2.0. More details through this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model).

Comment: Glad you got it to work on Cloud Functions :). For the Tensorflow missing module issue in the App Engine environment, I would like to invite you to opening up a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to investigate this matter further. As it will allow GCP specialists to provide a more narrowed down investigation into that particular issue.